# SQL Dates Problem - Count users that placed at least 1 order in at least 2 months out of last 6

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My timeframe is the 1st semester of 2020 --> 1/1 to 30/6
I want to count users that placed at least 1 order (or more) in at least 2 different months (or more) out of the 6

My data looks like:
user_id, order_date (e.g. 01/01/2020)

Working on redshift btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the group by and having as follows:

```
select user_id
  from your_Table t
 where <date between condition>
 group by user_id 
 having count(distinct date_trunc(month, order_date)) > 1
```

Comment: thanks! still got an issue (maybe bc of redshift?): Invalid operation: function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", integer, date) does not exist;    `select 
 analytical_customer_id
from 
 dwh_il.ranked_fct_order
where 
  order_date::date >= '2020-01-01' AND order_date::date <= '2020-06-30' 
 AND is_sent = TRUE
 group by 1 
 having count(distinct dateadd('month', datediff('month', 0, order_date::date), 0)) > 1`

Comment: I think that the problem is m or 'month' (tried both), that's the unknown for the formula

Comment: apparently it works! thanks a lot :) I just had to change to 'month'.

Comment: Great!! Good to know that it helped you

Comment: You can consider accepting the answer if it resolved your issue.